# Ubuntu 17.10 stuck in login loop after installing CUDA-9 and nvidia driver 390

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 17.10, cuda

I have Ubuntu-17.10. I was trying to install `tensorflow-gpu` and for that I needed CUDA-9. While installing CUDA-9 my graphics driver updated to nvidia-390.

Now when I restarted my PC. I'm stuck in a log in screen loop. I have tried editing the linux line `nvidia.modeset = 0`, `nomodeset`, `nouveau.modeset = 0`, all together. Nothing works.

Now one potential solution is to go back to the previous driver. For that, I enter TTY screen and enter my username, password. Now, this happens on TTY:

[image]

[image]

It goes back to the first login TTY screen in about 15 secs.

edit1:
Found a way to purge all the Nvidia drivers using ubuntu recovery mode. But still, the same problem continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you added something to your .bashrc or .profile during installation of either cuda or cudnn and probably made a mistake while doing so. If you boot into recovery mode you should be able to login as root, navigate to your user's home directory and investigate those files to look for errors.

If you do not find the error immediately, just move the files out of the way by renaming them. This way you should at least be able to login again.

If that doesn't help, try the same with the global shell configuration files in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile.d/*`

Comment: It didn't work. Nothing changed actually. Moments like these make me hate Ubuntu.

Comment: Please try checking again the files from my edited answer above.